# NVidia GTX 180 Composition Display Issues in After Effects and Premier Pro

Tags: after-effects

I have a new NVidia GTX 180 (latest drivers) which is one of the latest high end releases in the GPU market. The problem is I'm experiencing the following issues in the composition(viewport) windows in After Effects and Premier Pro.

Basically parts of the view become cropped out. If I scroll in/out parts of the footage become visible. The only way to see a comp fully is to zoom out incredibly far. Also sometimes the UI seems to be effected moving down the screen.

[image]
[image]

I should add that I work in After effects professionally, I have tried simple solutions like changing the view quality, clearing caches, preferences, etc.

I haven't received any feedback on Adobe's forums.

Comment: I would try using NVIDIA's clean driver tool to remove any video card drivers you have and then reboot and reinstall them and reboot again to see if that fixes it. I'm not 100% sure, but it could also be a bug as Premiere might not fully be compatible with the new gen cards.